# using float-type value in SQL commands

Tags: mysql, sql, database, floating-point

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third WHERE id2=$id2 AND divid=3.0");
```

this is my SQL command and it works well. but if i wnt to use `divid=3.1` (some float in here) instad of 3.0 it `mysqli_num_rows` returns 0. And i am perfectly sure  i have many `divid=3.1` column in my database.

```
`$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third WHERE id2=20 AND divid=3.1");` //this givs me mysqli_num_rows == 0;
```

Is there something different using float-type in SQL commands?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference with a `FLOAT` is that it's an approximate value. I just created a table with values `3` and `3.1`, and when I tried querying for `WHERE divid = 3.1` I didn't get any rows back either. I'm assuming that's because 3.1 ends up as something like 3.1000000000000001 or 3.0999999999999999.

Your options here are:

- Change your table so the `divid` column is a `DECIMAL` type.
- Cast `divid` to a `DECIMAL` when you use it in a `WHERE` clause:

  `SELECT * FROM third WHERE id2=20 AND CAST(divid AS DECIMAL(10,1))=3.1`
- Round `divid` when querying:

  `SELECT * FROM third WHERE id2=20 AND ROUND(divid, 1) = 3.1`

I recommend the first option if it's not too late in the project to change a column type.

Comment: i changed it to DECIMAL but my float numbers turns to integers. 3.1-->3 i need floting points in my database.

Comment: you need to specify a length and the number of decimal places when you use a 'decimal' column. i.e. 10,4 is 4 decimal places with 10 digits in total. manual: [precision-math-decimal-characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 0):

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE PRECISION` data types have a rounding behavior by design. You can't expect them to behave like exact numeric values.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-float.html

You should use `DECIMAL` (or its synonym `NUMERIC`) instead.

I tweeted about this last year: https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232

> If I had a dime for every time I've seen someone use FLOAT to store currency,
>   I'd have $999.997634. #ieee754jokes

Comment: i changed it to DECIMAL but my float numbers turns to integers. 3.1-->3 i need floting points in my database.

Comment: Specify a scale for your DECIMAL column, e.g. `DECIMAL(9,2)` allows two digits to the right of the decimal point. Read about this data type here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html